# Pronunciation of onomatopoeia, pharmacopoeia, etc

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, suffixes, greek

Words such as [onomatopoeia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/onomatopoeia) and [pharmacopoeia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pharmacopoeia) incorporate the Greek suffix *-poeia*, meaning *to make* or *to prepare*. Wiktionary's provided etymology for onomatopoeia reads:

> From Ancient Greek ὀνοματοποιία (**onomatopoiia**)

I'm curious to know how the Greek *onomatopoiia* is/was pronounced and if the *-poeia* suffix in the English equivalent has always been pronounced `/piːə/`.

Also, are there any words in English that have simplified *-poeia* to *-pia* or similar?

Comment: I'm not old enough to know how the Ancient Greeks pronounced ὀνοματοποιία, and I don't know anyone who is :-(

Comment: @AndrewLeach If Google Translate is any guide, _ὀνοματοποιία_ has survived into modern Greek too :)

Comment: How the Greeks pronounce Greek words isn't a question about English - however, the answer is easily found, e.g. in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%80%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%AF%CE%B1#Pronunciation).

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thank you. I missed that reference. I disagree that it isn't a question about English when you are comparing pronunciations of virtually identically spelt words and from the looks of it, words which are still in use in the source language; cf. questions on the the pronunciation of loan words on ELU. There's also the question of _when_ the word made it across into English. Also, simply because the root of the word resides in Ancient Greek does not imply that it was imported from then or there.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd suggest consider rewording your question with the clarifications from this last comment; your comment makes it more clear to me that you're after the English history of the word.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Probably [ɔnɔmatɔpoi'ia]. In English, it's ['anə'maɾə'pʰiyə] and ['farməkə'pʰiyə].

Comment: @JohnLawler In *American* English, it's /'anə'maɾə'pʰiyə/. In BrE, the first syllable is definitely a short "o" sound, among other changes.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: ['ɔnə'maɾə'pʰiyə] in UK, then.

Comment: ['ɔnə'matʰə'pʰiyə] for me. And ['fa:mə'kʰəʊpʰiə].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OED gives

> Pronunciation:  Brit.  /ˌɒnəmatəˈpiːə/ , U.S. /ˈˌɑnəˌmɑdəˈpiə/ ,
> /ˈˌɑnəˌmædəˈpiə/ Inflections:   Plural onomatopoeias, unchanged.
>
> Etymology:  < classical Latin *onomatopoeia* the making of words <
> Hellenistic Greek *ὀνοματοποιία* < ancient Greek *ὀνοματο*- onomato- comb.
> form + -*ποιία* -poeia comb. form. Compare Middle French, French
> *onomatopée* imitative formation of a word (1585), a word formed in this
> way (1768; 1665 as *omomatopeia* : compare sense 1b), Italian *onomatopea*
> (1560; a1498 as *onomatopia*), Old Occitan *onomothopeya* (c1330), Spanish
> *onomatopeya* (1450 as *onomatopeia*).
>
> N.E.D. (1903) gives the
> pronunciation as (onǫ:mătopī·yă, ǫ:nŏmă-) /əʊˌnɒmətəʊˈpiːjə/
> /ˌɒnəʊmæt-/ .

First use in English was:

> 1553   T. Wilson Arte of Rhetorique iii. f. 92v,   A worde makinge
> called of the Grecians *Onomatopeia* is when we make wordes of oure owne
> mynde, suche as be deriued from the nature of thinges.

They don't give any pronunciation history farther back than 1903.

It's instructive that Late Latin and the Romance languages usually pronounced this word's ending with an /e/ instead of an /i/:

- Latin *onomatopoeia* /-peia/ from earlier /-pojia/
- French *onomatopée* /-pe:/
- Italian *onomatopea* /-pea/ but also *onomatopia* /-pia/
- Old Occitan *onomothopeya* /-peja/
- Spanish *onomatopeya* & *onomatopeia* /-peja/

While the Greek underwent a vowel shift of the ending to [Modern Greek /-pi'ía/](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%AF%CE%B1). This reminded me of English's own [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) (GVS).  If the first use in English was as far back as 1553, then the vowel may have been subject to the GVS. In particular:

> Middle English [ɛː] raised to [eː] and then to modern English [iː] (as
> in beak).
> Middle English [eː] raised to Modern English [iː] (as in
> feet).

The above would result in an original /-peja/ becoming the modern /pija/. So, it seems possible that the original English borrowing from Latin/Greek had an /e/ and that it has changed to /i/ since then.

This is detective work and reasoning, not citation, so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: +1 And another for 'This is detective work and reasoning, not citation, so take it for what it's worth.'

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything in Mark Beadles' answer. I just wanted to address one point from the original question that wasn't covered yet.

It would not be standard to simplify “poeia” to “pia,” and I haven’t found any evidence of this occurring except as an occasional spelling error. In general, the digraph “oe” used to transliterate Greek "οι" can be simplified to “e.” This would yield the simplified spelling “onomatopeia.” [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/onomatopeia) does list this as a “US spelling of onomatopoeia,” but I haven’t found it listed by any other dictionaries, and [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onomatopeia%2Conomatopoeia%2C+onomatopia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conomatopeia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conomatopoeia%3B%2Cc0) indicates that “onomatopeia” is far less common as a spelling than “onomatopoeia”  even if we restrict the search to [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onomatopeia%2Conomatopoeia%2Conomatopia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conomatopeia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conomatopoeia%3B%2Cc0).